# how to access response value within a function in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

can someone please help me out, I have a for loop inside that there's a setTimout the call's the server after every second and the server responds with a value but when I try accessing the server response I get undefined. here is my code:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= latlng.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    GeoCoder.geocode({
      'address': latlng[i],
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (results) {
        var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng()
        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat()
      }
      console.log("are we getting location", lng + "" + lat)
    });
  }, i * 250);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code to be more readable and extracted the API call into a separate function. If you are using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/geocoder it should work.

```js
var GeoCoder = require("geocoder");

const addresses = [
  "South Road Morningside",
  "Hyde Park Shopping Centre",
  "Coachmans Crossing Cne Peter Place",
  "Watt Ave & 3rd Street",
];

const callApi = i =>
  GeoCoder.geocode(addresses[i], function(err, data) {
    console.log(i);
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });

for (let i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => callApi(i), i * 250);
}
```

Comment: Just tried that but still getting undefined when trying to console log the result

Comment: Please give a sample of the `latlng` array, a few elements.

Comment: here is the sample, var latlng = ['South Road Morningside', 'Hyde Park Shopping Centre', 'Coachmans Crossing Cne Peter Place', 'Watt Ave & 3rd Street',]

Comment: Are you using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/geocoder ?

Comment: for the google GeoCoder to work I have to pass an address object with the value of i. when i do so i can not access the result from GeoCoder but when checking on the network tab i can see the results. Here is how i passed it   GeoCoder.geocode({
            'address': addresses[i]
          },
          function (results, err) {
            console.log(i);
            if (results) {
              console.log(results);
            }
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          });

Answer (score 0):

Using promises gives you more control over handling responses across a range of iterations.

See the example below that could be adapted to replicate what you're trying to achieve:

```
function doWork(val) {
return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('in setTimeout:' + val);
  }, 1000);
});
}

async function newFunc(){
  let a = 5;
  const res1 = await doWork(a);
  console.log(res1);
  a = 1;
  console.log('out of setTimeout:' + a);
}

newFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function closure inside of the loop to lock in the state of the loop for each iteration, otherwise i will be length + 1 as the loop would have finished by the time the setTimeout is called giving you the error.

Since you are using setTimout, rather than creating a closure inside the loop you can use the native argument passing of setTimeout. setTimout will pass any argument past the 2nd to the callback function.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= latlng.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(i) { // <-- consume the i variable
    GeoCoder.geocode({
      'address': latlng[i],
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (results) {
        var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng()
        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat()
      }
      console.log("are we getting location", lng + "" + lat)
    });
  }, i * 250, i); // <-- pass in i here as an argument to setTimeout
}
```

Comment: Using `let` to initialize `i` in the for loop causes a new environment record to be created for each iteration of the loop, where `i` will be stored. `latlng[i]` inside the anonymous timer callback function sees the environment record for the iteration which set up the callback in its scope chain. There is no  particular need to pass `i` as an argument via `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the https://github.com/wyattdanger/geocoder package the formal arguments for the callback function are reversed.

Replacing `function(results, status)` with `function(status, results)` should fix the typo.

At the moment, because there is no error, the conditional branch

```
  if (results) { // actually testing the error argument
     // set lng and lat
  }
```

is never taken, leaving `lng` and `lat` set to `undefined` from when they were declared.